# find top the hashtags - mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I want to use the SELECT to find words are found in the database column 'keyword' (regardless of lowercase and uppercase letters), and arrange them in order based on the number of special mention are mentioned in the table.

```
id | keyword
------------
1  | mysql
2  | php
3  | twitter
4  | MySQL
5  | javascript
6  | html
7  | css
8  | JavaScript
9  | MYSQL
```

if only sorted by the number of repetitions of the keywords alone.

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select keyword, count(*) as appearances
from your_table
group by keyword
order by count(*) desc
```

If that does not do a case-insensitive grouping then you can define a case-insensitive collation like this

```
group by keyword collate utf8_general_ci
```